# JPA not fetching data throwing stackoverflow error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a very large json to store and I divided that into following five entities and trying to store to h2 database using spring-data-jpa,inserting is working fine into database, but while fetching A object with A primary key Id, I am getting stackoverflow error, because there is circular dependency.

could someone help me to figure out what is the issue.

Top class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@Data
public class A{

@Id
@Column(name = "a_id")
private String id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String name2;

@Column
private String name3;

@Column
private String name4;

@Column
private String name5;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "a",fetch = 
FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<B> b;
}
```

Second class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@Data
public class B{

@Id
@Column(name = "bname")
private String bname;

@Column
private String bVersion;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "b")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<C> cs;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
@JsonBackReference
private A a;
}
```

Third class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class C{

@Id
@Column(name = "cname")
private String cName;


@Column
private String cVersion;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "c")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<D> ds;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bname")
@JsonBackReference
private B b;
}
```

Fourth class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class D{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="d_id")
private long id;

@Column
private String dName;

@Column
private String dName2;


@ElementCollection
@Column
private List<String> dNames;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "d")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<E> e;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cname")
@JsonBackReference
private C c;

}

Fifth class

@Entity
@Data
public class E{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "e_id")
private long id;

@Column
private String ename;

@Column
private String eName2;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "e_id")
@JsonBackReference
private E e;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: Please share the exception you are getting along with your code to fetch data

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem and spent the whole day. Finally, I found its problem with the `toString` method generated by Lombok using `@Data` annotation.

**Solution:**

Override, `toString` method and write your own implementation. If you do not want to use `toString` then use `@Getter` and `@Setter` instead of `@Data`.

**Why**

Note: This occurs with bi-directional relationship.
Lets say I have two entity and having bi-directional relationship.

```
@data
Entity1{
  @oneToMany
  public List<Entity2> entity2s;

  //Added by lombok while using @Data
  @Generated
    public String toString() {
        return "entity2s=" + this.getEntity2s() + ")";
    }
}

@data
Entity2{
  @ManytoOne
  public Entity1 entity1;


  //Added by lombok while using @Data
  @Generated
  public String toString() {
    return "entity1=" + this.getEntity1() + ")";
  }

}
```

In above example, toString()(called by JPA) of Entity1 calles `toString()` of Entity2 and `toString()` of Entity2 calls `toString()` of Entity1. And that is how circular reference is building.

Note: The same goes to `hashCode` method.

Here is a some reference links,

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1007

https://interviewbubble.com/stackoverflow-tostring-method-when-using-lombok/

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how Lomboks `toString` method caused problems? I use `@Data` all the time and haven't seen a problem like this.

Comment: Added in Why section.